# filtrar datos en python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente lista de archivos

```
[
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B1.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B2.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B3.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B4.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B5.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B6.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B7.TIF'
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_BQA.TIF']
```

desde la cual necesito filtrar solo las que terminen en B1 a Bn (7 en este caso)
El nombre del archivo puede ser cualquier cantidad de caractares, y cualquier combinacion.. lo unico que se asegura es que antes del . viene una B mas un numero correlativo

es decir:

JKHJGJHGJHGJLOQUESEAB1.TIF      **es un nombre valido**

kdjshfskdjfhLOQUESEA B1.TIF     **es un nombre valido**

slkdfjlCUALQUIER COSA_B1Y.TIF   **NO ES VALIDO**

Para ello, tengo el siguiente código en python

```
for archivoImagenEncontrado in archivosImagenEncontrados:
    archivo = Path(archivoImagenEncontrado).name
    print(f"{archivo} contiene : ",any(chr.isdigit() for chr in archivo))
```

pero esto no me sirve, ya que en el ultimo ítem, si me dice que tiene un numero y es porque en la parte anterior hay precisamente números
como hago para evaluar solo la parte final del nombre del archivo?? es decir desde la B hasta antes del .

Saludos y gracias por leer

Comment: Si el número de caracteres que quieres evaluar fueran siempre el 6 y 5 de derecha a izquierda podrías utilizar slices, por ejemplo nombreArchivo[-6:-4]. Pero en el último caso son 3 caracteres en lugar de 2, en ese caso tal vez un regex

Comment: hola..  lamentablemente no es el caso.. ni siquiera podria haber usado el split('_') para haber partido la cadena en base a algun caracter, ya que estos nombres se generan aleatoriamente, y lo unico fijo en el patron es la B + un numero correlativo desde 1 a n antes del punto.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solución usando python puro

Una forma de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

files = [
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B1.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B2.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B3.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B4.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B5.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B6.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B7.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_BQA.TIF',
'kjsdhkjshdfB11.TIF',
'holab.tif']

def es_bnumero(file):
    has_number = False
    
    for char in file.stem[::-1]:
        if(char in "0123456789"):
            has_number = True
        else:
            return (has_number and char == "B")
        
    return False

filtrado = []

for file in files:
    file = Path(file)

    if(es_bnumero(file)):
        filtrado.append(file)

pprint(filtrado)
```

El plan es que por cada archivo, creamos un objeto Path, obtenemos su nombre sin la extensión y, finalmente, si la función is_bnumero devuelve True, lo agregamos a la lista.

**Lo que hace esta función es lo siguiente**

Recorre el nombre del archivo (sin la extensión) de derecha a izquierda. Verifica que cada caracter esté en "0123456789" y, si está, se establece la variable has_number en True (como la inicializamos en False, solo será True si se encuentra al menos un caracter numerico al final de la cadena). Si no lo está, significa que el número al final que estabamos revisando finalizó (o nunca estuvo allí), y retornamos verdadero solo si has_number es verdadero y el caracter no numerico que nos encontramos es igual a "B".
Si el bucle for termina sin más, devolvemos False.

Nota: no uso isdigit, isnumeric ni isdecimal por que no quiero que se acepten caracteres que no sean numeros "normales" ni el 0. Esto lo aprendí hoy. Lectura recomendada: https://miguendes.me/python-isdigit-isnumeric-isdecimal

**Esto simplemente valida que**

Haya una serie de caracteres númericos seguidos al final de la cadena precedidos por una B mayuscula. Esto significa que B00010.tif también es considerado valido. Si deseas que ese escenario no se considere valido, comunicamelo en los comentarios.

En el momento que una de estas condiciones de Falso, las restantes no se evalúan y el if dará falso.

#### Solución usando expresiones regulares

Esta solución es la más clara y simple, pero requiere aprenderse un nuevo "lenguaje", (por lo que tengo entendido) es más lenta y requiere usar un modulo adicional de la librería estandar. Pero habrá veces que es considerablemente más facil usar regex que código "normal".

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
import re

files = [
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B1.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B2.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B3.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B4.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B5.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B6.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_B7.TIF',
'LT05_L1TP_233083_20111117_20161005_01_T1_BQA.TIF',
'kjsdhkjshdfB11.TIF',
'holab.tif',
"inicioB2final.tif"]

# compilamos previamente la expresión regular para que
# no tenga que ser compilada cada vez que se usa.
# La r al principio de la cadena dice "la \ no tiene ningún significado especial en la mayoría de los casos".
# si no ponemos esto, "\n" sería un salto de linea por ejemplo.    
filtro = re.compile(r"B\d+$")

filtrado = []

for file in files:
    file = Path(file)

    if(filtro.search(file.stem)):
        filtrado.append(file)

pprint(filtrado)
```

El método search de la expresión regular compilada devuelve None (evaluado como False cuando se pone en condicional) cuando no se encontró nada o un objeto Match (evaluado como True) el cual no nos va a importar más allá de obtener su valor de verdad.

La regex usada es esta:

```
B\d+$
```

- `B`: sería una B mayuscula, seguida de...
- `\d+`: \d significa "un número", el + significa "una o más coincidencias de la expresión anterior". Por lo tanto, esto significa "uno o más números". Seguido de...
- `$`: Representa al final de la cadena (NO el ultimo caracter). Esto le indica a la regex que la expresión anterior debe estar "pegada" al final de la cadena.

Nota: Esta regex hace exactamente lo mismo que la versión en Python puro. Eso significa que tiene las mismas cosas a tener en cuenta.

Aunque a veces no esté de acuerdo con las regex, estas son muy poderosas, fascinantes y sirven cuando se necesita analizar de forma compleja una cadena. Si querés aprender más de como funcionan en Python, aquí te dejo [el link a la documentación de re](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html)

Comment: esta super bien.. aunque..  este algoritmo fallaría cuando el nombre del archivo sea kjsdhkjshdfB11.TIF lo cual tb es un nombre de archivo valido

Comment: Gracias por el aviso, edité la respuesta para ajustarla a lo que buscas @LuisGabrielFabres

Comment: Es la ocasión de usar expresiones regulares.

Comment: Sabés que? Voy a agregar una versión en expresiones regulares. Es más divertido usar un bucle for, además de que las regex son más lentas, por eso pienso conservarlo.

Answer (score 0):

creo que ya di con una solución, aunque no me gusta mucho, pero al menos sirve.
La dejo por acá por si alguien mas le puedas servir.

```
for archivoImagenEncontrado in archivosImagenEncontrados:
    archivo = Path(archivoImagenEncontrado).name
    for numero in range(1,9):
        if archivo.__contains__(f"B{numero}{extensionImagen}"):
            print(f"{archivo}")
```

la idea es que por cada archivo se utilice la instruccion **contain**  (o tambien sirve "in") y que busque por un patron especifico en este caso B mas una parte variable que es un numero del 1 al 9 para el cual se hace una iteracion en un ciclo for numero in range(1,9)
esto hace que por cada archivo se realice un test para ver si contiene B1... B2...B3.. asi sucesivamente hasta dar con alguna coincidencia, y actuar en consecuencia..
espero les sirva
saludos

Comment: No olvides explicar cómo funciona el código. Puede que para vos sea obvio, pero para otros no. Recordá que las respuestas son _para todos_.

Comment: Dos cosas sobre tu solución. Primero, es mejor usar in en lugar de \_\_contains\_\_. Segundo, tu condicional daría True en archivos que contengan en alguna parte B[numero].[extensión]. Por ejemplo inicio*B2.png*final.png

Comment: hola dante..  gracias por lo de "in" la verdad soy medio nuevo en python, no me manejo mucho en que sentencias son mejores que otras.. por otro lado respecto del la extension, la lista esta previamente filtrada para que siempre sean archivos de un solo tipo (en este caso tif).

Comment: hola padaleiana, si claro.. lo dejare en la respuesta. gracias por tus comentarios

Comment: En realidad, in llama internamente a \_\_contains\_\_, pero es más claro usar in. Por otro lado, entiendo lo que dices, pero incluso si es tif, el fallo seguirá sucediendo, por ejemplo, con inicio*B2.tif*final.tif.